# I am trying to find a 1980 cartoon that has glasses that changes colors when you tell the truth or a lie

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I don't have much to go on since I am 41 and it has been long time. All I can remember is a desert planet, motor bike or vehicles, someone useing glases that turned red or green depending on if you told the truth or a lie, and a character named Papaya or something similar to that. It has the same artistry as BraveStarr.

Comment: One of these, presumably? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_produced_by_Filmation